# Javascript function based on screen width

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hey I'm trying to decrease the column width of masonry when you get to screen size with:
max-width: 450px;

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box',
    columnWidth: 220,
    isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
    isFitWidth: true
  });
});
```

Here is my Javascript code. What do I add to make it decrease the column width at that screen size??

Or how do I target screen size with an IF statement...if screen size is less than 450 then 'xyz' else the function above...

Comment: This is easiest done with css to be honest.

Comment: Agree with Robin. However, some variables you might find useful in JS:

For inner screen size within the browser:

window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight

For total screen size:

screen.width / screen.height

Answer (score 0):

A shorthand IF statement should do the trick. Essentially, you are saying if document width is less than 450 than columnWidth is set to 220, else columnWidth is set to 110.

```
var $container = $('#container');
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
                          itemSelector : '.box',
                          columnWidth: ( $(document).width() < 450 ? 220 : 110 ),
                          isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
                          isFitWidth: true
                        });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.screen.availWidth < 450)
{
    // alternative configuration here
}
```